# hide parent div if child div is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

Hod Do i hide the parent div EventsRollup if the child div RelatedEventsList is empty??

```
<div class="EventsRollup">
<span class="EventsRollupTitle">CPR &amp; Health Safety Classes</span><br /><br/>                                                             
  <div class="RelatedEventsList">   
  <!--EMPTY with a lot of whitespaces etc. but no text-->
  </div>
</div><!--END EventsRollup-->
```

Why is this not doing it?

```
var listtext=$.trim($('.RelatedEventsList').text());
if (listtext===""){
     $('.EventsRollup').hide();  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing length instead of null?

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/3E3Y2/.

Comment: try `if (listtext==""){`

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3V5Vs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.text()` may return spaces and line breaks.

```
if (!/\S/.test(listtext)){
     $('.EventsRollup').hide();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work fine, although i usually do the following

```
var listtext=$.trim($('.RelatedEventsList').text());
if (listtext.length === 0){
     $('.EventsRollup').hide();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `html()` function:

```
var listText = $.trim($('.RelatedEventsList').html());
if(listText == '') {
    $('.EventsRollup').hide;
}
```